# Apache nifi - how to implement "Continue if no records found in GetMongo processor"

Tags: mongodb, apache-nifi

In my project I'm reading data from a mongo database on a schedule, performing some processing on each *new* row, and then forwarding to another processor.

I want to ensure that none of the records I read from mongo have already been processed, so I'm using a second mongoDB collection as a tracking table.

I'd like to have logic that works like this:

- Read from initial database [`GetMongo` Processor]
- If record doesn't exist yet in tracking DB [`GetMongo`], insert it [`PutMongo`]
- If record exists already in tracking DB, terminate flow (We can assume it's already been processed)
- Tracking DB will be queried later by a separate processor in another flow on another schedule

My problem is in the "continue only if doesn't exist in tracking table" step.

If I use a `GetMongo` processor, it appears to terminate the flow when no records are returned. It follows the `success` path when results *are* returned, but I want to terminate that anyway. For both records and no_records results, the `original` path is triggered with the original file, but I don't think that's going to help me in this flow.

I'm leaning towards using an `ExecuteScript` processor and just using Mongo's db.collection.count() functionality via ECMAScript which I can then route on, but ideally I'd like a cleaner option if it's possible.

Comment: I expected "success" and "failure" to play such a trigger. But it didn't work well, I give up in pure "GetMongo".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the `DetectDuplicate` processor, I decided that the cache-nature of it made it unsuitable for my purposes.

I ended up using the maven archetype to create a custom processor to handle this logic which split into `matched` and `unmatched` relationships based on whether the query had any reuslts or not.

Link to the archetype to create your own processor - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.nifi/nifi-processor-bundle-archetype